# window.ethereum in ThirdWebSDK

Tags: web3js, web3-react, thirdweb

I am using the web3.js library to interact with my smart contracts.
To create a Web3 object, I use window.etherum like this `Web3(window.etherum)`.

We are migrating to the ThirdWeb library. In particular the EVM SDK for React.

In this way, I can handle the interaction with the blockchain also with mobile application.

The problem is that I would like to have a Web3 object in order to use the source code that I already have.

I saw that ThirdWeb support ethers.js (by creatin a ethers.js provider), but I have already all my source code in web3.js.

Which is the equivalent of window.etherum in ThirdWeb? Or there is a way to get a Web3 object from ThirdWeb?